# add new items/folders to a TreeView - VueJS + Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, treeview, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add new items to a treeview I created using Vuetify layout. The source code is here: https://codepen.io/luizarusso/pen/YzPqNpy

```
  methods: {    
    addChildFile(item) {
      if (!item.children) {
        this.$set(item, "children", []);
      }

      const name = 'kkk';
      const file = 'pdf';
      item.children.push({
        name,
        file
      });
    },
    addChildFolder(item) {
      if (!item.children) {
        this.$set(item, "children", []);
      }

      const name = 'kkk';
      const id = this.nextId++;
      item.children.push({
        id,
        name
      });
    },
}
```

It works fine! But I need to provide a dialog where the user should select the file to upload or insert the folder name. At this point, when I'm trying to insert inside a child node, I loose the index of the node I want to insert the new file/folder.

This is the closest I got: https://codepen.io/luizarusso/pen/dyPORda

```
  methods: {    
    addFile (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      this.dialog = true
    },

    addFolder (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      this.dialog2 = true
    },

    addChildFile() {
      if (!this.editedItem.children) {
        this.$set(this.editedItem, "children", []);
      }
      const id = this.nextId++;
      const name = this.fd[0].name;
      const file = 'pdf';
      this.editedItem.children.push({
        id,
        name,
        file
      });
      this.dialog = false
    },

    addChildFolder() {
      if (!this.editedItem.children) {
        this.$set(this.editedItem, "children", []);
      }

      const name = this.nomePasta;
      const id = this.nextId++;
      this.editedItem.children.push({
        id,
        name
      });
      this.dialog2 = false
    },
  }
```

Is there a way to keep the bind? Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Djip's answer solved the problem. Here is the source code with the solution, in case someone would like to see: https://codepen.io/luizarusso/pen/MWYbZVP
As he explained, you just have to use = sign to set the editedItem variable to the correct item, and not a copy of it (when using Object.assign)

```
    addFile (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = item
      this.dialog = true
    },

    addFolder (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = item
      this.dialog2 = true
    },
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Object.assign({}, item);`. What `Object.assign` does, it copying the object, and removing the reference.

So you should change your code to the following:

```
methods: {    
    addFile (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = item
      this.dialog = true
    },

    addFolder (item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item)
      this.editedItem = item
      this.dialog2 = true
    },
```

This way, you're setting your `editedItem` variable, to the correct item, and not a copy of it.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I don't even know how to thank you! 
I'm new to this and your answer just solved the problem. Thanks for explaining the reason why, it's clear for me now.
Thanks a lot lot!!
Here is the source code with the solution, in case someone would like to see: https://codepen.io/luizarusso/pen/MWYbZVP